# How I do find properties name list of a object

Tags: c++, spidermonkey, jsapi

JSAPI provide function JS_GetProperty to get specified property name's value
but how to get them as name list / all properties name ?

found similar issue on link below
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine/usHtJn4LR7A

Thank you very much ,sir

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this. The older [JS_Enumerate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_Enumerate) function or the combination of [JS_NewPropertyIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_NewPropertyIterator) and [JS_NextProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_NextProperty). I would recommend the latter, because you don't have to mess around with the jsid array yourself.

Comment: I try with JS_NewPropertyIterator/JS_NextProperty it will return JSID , but I want all property name of the object . Please advise me more , than you very much